# How to import all imports of another .py file

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, project, system

#### Info

- python version: 3
- development environment: eclipse luna

#### Goal

I'm currently developing an addon system for a program. My Idea was to create a file where I import all addons. This file is generated during the addon instalation process (when you click the button: install addon). It looks like that:

```
import testaddon1
import testaddon2
import bigaddon.startup as bigaddon
```

When I start my programm I want to import all files/modules to read some properties and automaticly implement the addons in my program.

#### Question

How can I start import statements that are written in a different file.

file1.py

```
def test():
   print('test')
```

file2.py

```
import file1.py.test as test
```

file3.py

```
#run the import commands from file2.py
test()
```

console output after running file3.py:

```
test
```

#### What I want

- an answer on how to achieve the previous result
- a different idea on how to create an addon system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

file.py

```
def hello():
    print('hello')
```

file2.py

```
import file

file.hello()
```

file3.py

```
from file2 import *

file.hello()
```

executing file 3.  `greg@ja python file3.py`

Comment: I know that that works, bu I want to have the import statements in an extra file. I want to create an addon system. The user should click install addon and a program copies the .py file into the addons folder, writes the import statement in an specific file. If I now restart the program it should be able to read that file and import all modules that are written down in this file.

Comment: Ok. Do you have an idea on how to do an addon system without the import problem?